# Mojave not recognizing my bootable USB stick, reverts back to Apple Partition after flashing

Tags: mojave, partition, usb, catalina, unix

So first of all I have little experience on this field, but I'm trying to install linux on my personal MacBook Pro from 2017.

I followed a lot of tutorials for this but none of them worked. So I figured I'd ask here.

I have a 64gb SanDisk Ultra Media USB stick lying around. I got it here: https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_sandisk-ultra-usb-3-0-flashdrive-64-gb-1262970.html

I grabbed a ubuntu copy from the official Ubuntu website, used Etcher to flash to ISO on the stick. Everything seemed fine, so I eject the stick, restart my macbook into startup manager, but the USB isn't there. Only my internal hard drive shows up. After reading a lot of forums I read that the USB stick should be erased first with GUID partition.

So, I did that, but after flashing I checked Disk Utility and saw that the partition was reverted back to the standard Apple-partition scheme.

What am I doing wrong? All these miracle fixes I see on the internet never work for me, and people say it's so easy to install Linux on your Mac. Well, I also have a MacBook from work, with Catalina, and have the same problem with that one too!

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try to format it in any other device, any format type, give it a new name. Eject afterwards then re-insert. Does it still appear to revert to the original structure? If so, the firmware write-protect has been triggered & the stick is toast, I'm afraid.

Comment: Okay well, then it's probably toast. I tried your steps and after flashing it reverted back to apple partition

Comment: There's a more detailed workthrough on our sister site, Super User - http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only - which might be worth a look at, but I wouldn't be too hopeful, sorry.

Comment: Well, I just tried another USB stick, same problem :/. Just wanna install linux man :(

Comment: Have you tested these sticks are actually the 64GB they claim to be? There are a lot of fakes around, 4GB pretending to be bigger, first time you cross the 4GB barrier they break. There's a freeware fake detector - Fight Flash Fraud app [F3X](https://github.com/insidegui/F3X)

Comment: They are fine. Also I used the 64gb a couple times before for school. Could it be the .iso I'm using? I've downloaded the latest ubuntu copy, but haven't tested it with other distro's, like mint for example.

Comment: Exactly which copy did you grab. Does the file have a name?

Comment: I don't know how it could be the iso [but equally I can't say it definitely isn't]; usually this firmware lock triggers on a write error. If the iso was dodgy it would trigger a read error on the drive it's currently on, which would be a graceful quit for the write process.

Comment: @DavidAnderson the name of the file: ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso

@ Tetsujin yeah you're probably right, but I'm pretty lost at this point so I guess it could be anything. It's pretty frustrating really

Comment: @Tetsujin could another reason be that I use a usb-c to usb-a connector? because my macbook only has usb-c ports.

Comment: It could potentially be the weak point, but I really couldn't say for sure.

Comment: @Tetsujin that was the problem at the end! I tried a different connector and it worked this time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case it seemed to be my USB-C to USB-A connector. I used a different one and it worked.